How to identify 'Deploying new version to instance' state of AWS EBS environment in a lambda function?
I have a lambda function which (I assume) should be configured to get triggered by EventBridge (Cloudwatch Events)
When I deploy new environment version into Elastic beanstalk (EBS) I can see under Environment's Events tab event with title "Deploying new version to instance(s)."
How can I identify this event in my lambda function?
